# Conditionally importing a MySQL dump file

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, backup, restore

I have an SQL back up file for two full fields (ID, and COUNT) from a table (CATEGORIES) and I need to import them into another identical table on another backup database where COUNT is currently default to 0.

When restoring I get an error message that the IDs do exist, which is true but all I need to restore/update is each COUNT into the corresponding ID field. How can I accomplish this with mysqldump or through phmyadmin.

The backup SQL file includes over a Million pairs of values (ID, COUNT).

Answer (score 0):

You may want  to use replace option with mysqldump:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_replace

something like

```
mysqldump --replace -uroot -p123456 mydb > export.sql
```